# What is the character sequence in "Data" that is shown when you capture the ping command in Wireshark?

Tags: networking, ping, wireshark

In all my ping captures I have this `abcdef...` sequence in "data", is there something relevant about it or is it just dummy data? Is there any purpose of it other than measuring round-trip time?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just padding the packet so it reaches the minimum Ethernet frame size of
64 bytes (hex 40).

Because the ICMP segment is smaller than 64 it needs to be padded up to meet the minimum. This is done by just adding in the alphabet until the minimum is reached.

See Wikipedia
[Ethernet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame).

Answer (score 0):

The payload isn't necessarily *just* padding.  In fact, the payload can even be used to some degree to fingerprint the OS.  In this case, I'd be willing to bet that the ping was run from a Windows machine due to 2 things:

1. The lack of a timestamp in the payload
2. The Identifier is 1

Contrast that with a Mike Muuss-based ping (FreeBSD, Mac OSX, ...) where:

1. The first 8 bytes of the payload represent a timestamp (struct tv32)
2. The Identifier is the lower 16-bits of the process ID of the `ping` program itself.

Or on Solaris, the timestamp is a "struct timeval" where the seconds value might have a 64-bit seconds field.  Other OS's may vary the payload as well.

For reference, you can read the comments on an old Wireshark Bug, namely [Bug 5770](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=5770).

Of course there are other uses for the ICMP payload as well, such as for ICMP Tunneling.  Here's just one article that talks about this, titled, [Ping Power - ICMP Tunnel](https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/ping-power-icmp-tunnel-31e2abb2aaea).

In any case, the ICMP payload is not necessarily just padding.